# iOS status bar active app

Tags: ios

When Google Maps iOS app is running in the background, or when a phone call is running in background, the status bar shows the "Google Maps is currently using your location" and similarly the phone call app changes the status bar too. How do I make my app show a similar bar when running in the background?

Answer (score 2):

The green "in a call" bar only shows when using the Phone app or VOIP apps on an active call. The blue "using navigation" bar only shows for navigation apps actively providing navigation.

There's no general support to show a colored bar for other uses.

If your app is a VOIP app or a navigation app, iOS will show the proper bar for you at the proper time.

Comment: how to show, call duration if app is in background along with red color status bar?